# How to setup Oracle SQL developer Modeler 4.0.3 for MariaDB?

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have input the JDBC driver from MariaDB. But how to get the data.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select File > Import > Data Dictionary[image]

After setup your connection to the db and follow the wizard.

Comment: I know, but what to set in the Data Dictionary. Because everything i tried doesn't function

Comment: You need setup connection, press add, select the jdbc tabsheet and fill the correct connection string, test the connection and save it. Choose the connection and press next.

Comment: I don't have a JDBC tabsheet. There is only Oracle. I don't know why :( But if it would be an JDBC tabsheet, this would be the answer.

Comment: Goto Tools -> Preferences, Navigate to Database -> Third Party JDBC Drivers and add your driver, after restart the ide. The tabsheet should be there after this operations.

Comment: My navigation path is completly different from yours. Do you use 4.0.3? I set the maria jdbc driver in the settings yesterday also, but still doesn't function. I cannot translate my path, because i use german version, but i can try. In german version my path is extras->voreinstellungen...->JDBC-Treiber eines anderen Herstellers. In english extras->presetting...->JDBC-Driver of a different vendor. This is not the accurate wording, but you see it differs. In the last setting the driver mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar is set since yesterday, but still doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: I managed the thing i want(ER-modell) with MySQL Workbench, but it would still be nice to get it work with the SQL data modeler for the next time.